# Windows 7 unmounts D: when sleeping

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sleep

I've got a Lenovo laptop with Windows 7, which has an SSD as C: and an HDD as D:, and no CD/DVD/BD drive, because the HDD is in the removable disk drive bay (at least I assume it is the HDD, did not actually look at the physical drive in there).

The problem is, Windows thinks D: drive is removable. This in itself is merely inconvenient, I just have to be careful to not unmount it accidentally from systray. The bigger problem is, when going to standby and coming back Windows unmounts the drive, or at least tries (failing if there are locked files).

After it gets ejected, the drive is completely gone until reboot. Scanning for hardware changes in Device Manager does not find it, for instance.

- How do I tell Windows 7 that D: drive is not removable?
- Or failing that, how do I tell Windows to not try to eject it when going to sleep?
- And, how do I bring it back after it gets unmounted, without rebooting?

Comment: Is this http://superuser.com/questions/92264/internal-sata-hard-disk-shows-up-as-removable-device-on-windows-7 your problem

Comment: @Tog Possible. Symptoms are same, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Update your SATA driver : If amd chipset than it bundled with their Chipset driver
and

If INTEL than install [Intel Rapid Storage Technology](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Software%20Products&ProductLine=Chipset%20Software&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%20Rapid%20Storage%20Technology) driver

Or if you wish to use Microsoft provide AHCI driver than install this hotfix

MS KB article : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977178

Citation : [HDD Disappears after sleep mode](https://superuser.com/questions/426288/hdd-disappears-after-sleep-mode)

Another thread : [Internal SATA hard disk shows up as removable device on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/92264/internal-sata-hard-disk-shows-up-as-removable-device-on-windows-7)